# Can there be an optimised approach to this question?

Tags: java, optimization

Given integers N and M, find the number of ordered pairs (a, b) such that 1≤a <b≤N and ((M mod a) mod b) = ((M mod b) mod a).

Input
The first line contains an integer T, the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.

The only line of each test case contains two integers N, M.

output
For each test case, output in a single line the answer to the problem.

Constraints
1≤T≤1000

2≤N≤10 ^ 6

1≤M≤5⋅10 ^ 5

The sum of N over all test cases does not exceed 10 ^ 6

I have tried O (N ^ 2) approach but it gives TLE. Need a new approach or any idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            int testCase = scn.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCase; i++) {
                int n = scn.nextInt();
                int m = scn.nextInt();
                int count = 0;
                for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k <= n; k++) {
                        if (((m % j) % k) == ((m % k) % j)) {
                            // System.out.print(j+" "+k);
                            // System.out.println();
                            count++;
                        }

                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, unrelated, but you should **never** swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I can see some improvements. First of all, since a<b, (M mob a) mod b = M mod a

So we have to check whether M mod a = (M mod b) mod a, but this means that a divides (M - (M mod b))=((M div b) * b)

To sum up, we have to iterate over all b=1,...,n and for each of them we have to count the divisors of ((M div b) * b) which are less than b.

The improvement is the fact that ((M div b) * b) is comparable with b, and when we are looking for the divisor of ((M div b) * b) we can stop at its square root.

A possible implementation (in which I have removed the tests cases) is this one

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scn.nextInt();
        int m = scn.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k <= n; k++) {
                if (((m % j) % k) == ((m % k) % j)) {
                    //System.out.print(j+" "+k);
                    //System.out.println();
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        count=0;
        for (int b = 1; b <= n; b++) {
            //System.out.println((m/b)*b);
            count += countDivisors(m, b);
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}

private static int countDivisors(int m,  int b) {
    int count=0;
    int val = ((m/b)*b);
    int mi = Math.min((int)Math.sqrt(val), b-1);
    if(mi == 0)
        return (b-1);
    for(int a=1; a<=mi; a++) {
        if(val % a == 0) {
            count++;
            int aa=val/a;
            if(aa>a && aa < b) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Comment: i liked your appraoch , but still not that optimised.thanks for the help tho.